# kinect, c# how to resolve NullReferenceException when I use NavigationService?

Tags: c#, kinect, nullreferenceexception, navigationservice

[image]

Like this capture's source code,
I want to use NavigationService's `GoBack() method` when my gesture is recognized.
(this source code is MainWindows.Gestures.cs)

But, When I use GoBack() method in somethig.xaml,
there is not exception.

I added all reference.
please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Obviously `NavigationService` is null, but we can´t guess *why* it is because you didn´t provide the code where you declare and set this variable.